# Migrating from Spring Security 5.x Bcrypt hashes to Quarkus

Tags: bcrypt, quarkus

I'm attempting to rewrite an application that was originally developed with Spring. The user authentication is provided via Spring Security that uses Bcrypt to generate and check hashed passwords.

They are stored in the database in the format shown below. As far as I can tell, this is how it is represented:

```
|  |RR|        Salt          |      Hashed Password        |
$2a$10$Dh23I3CO6l1n3mOofdazreNLg2OHxzDrxyGGZEstTbITKs.cX3N/u
```

(Where `RR` is the number of rounds)

I've tried migrating this to a new table structure as show in "*Table 3. Example Table*" under *Using a Hashed Password Representation* of [4.6. Component Documentation](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#component-documentation), for example:

```
NAME | PASSWORD                        | SALT                   |ITERATION_COUNT|
=====|=================================|========================|===============|
test | NLg2OHxzDrxyGGZEstTbITKs.cX3N/u | Dh23I3CO6l1n3mOofdazre | 10            |
```

I have configured the mapper in `application.properties` as below:

```
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.sql=SELECT u.password, u.salt, u.iteration_count FROM test_user u WHERE u.name=?
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.enabled=true
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.password-index=1
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.hash-encoding=base64
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.salt-index=2
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.salt-encoding=base64
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.iteration-count-index=3
```

However, I either get an error caused by invalid base64 characters (which isn't a total surprise as the implementation in Spring Security states it's not a MIME compatible base64 implementation) or, when that error is not present, it fails to verify the password.

How would I be able to migrate all the users to the Bcrypt implementation that Quarkus uses?

Answer (score 6):

So I didn't need to split up the *salt*, *hash* and *iteration count* at all. You can continue to use the current 'single string' format. The trick is to configure the mapper as follows (note the `-1` for the `salt` and `iteration-count` properties):

```
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.enabled=true
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.password-index=1
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.salt-index=-1
quarkus.security.jdbc.principal-query.bcrypt-password-mapper.iteration-count-index=-1
```

Although I don't see it mentioned in the [Wildfly Elytron](https://docs.wildfly.org/17/WildFly_Elytron_Security.html#component-documentation) docs, or in the [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/guides/security-jdbc#quarkus-elytron-security-jdbc_configuration) configuration documentation, it is clearly handled (see [PasswordKeyMapper.java](https://github.com/wildfly-security/wildfly-elytron/blob/1.x/auth/realm/jdbc/src/main/java/org/wildfly/security/auth/realm/jdbc/mapper/PasswordKeyMapper.java#L250) on GitHub)

The logic caters for when these two properties are set to `-1`. It then parses the full string and verifies the password successfully.